# Conditional package dependencies

Tags: rhel, rpm, rpm-spec

I am creating an RPM package for Red Hat Enterprise Linux. My software requires the 'redhat-lsb' package when running on RHEL 7 and 8, but does not require it on RHEL 9. Furthermore, the package isn't even available from the RHEL 9 repositories.

If I include that package on a `Requires:` line, then the package installation fails on RHEL9.

If I put the `Requires` line inside a conditional expression like this:

```
%if 0%{?rhel} <= 8
Requires: redhat-lsb
%endif
```

Then the condition is evaluated at build time, and, because I build on RHEL7, the resultant package always has the dependency.

Is there an automated way to make the dependency conditional on the version of the OS at install time? If not, what would be the best way to resolve the problem? If I don't add it to the `Requires:` list, then does it have to be installed manually?

Can I, for example, make the requirement optional?

Comment: the `rhel` macro should contain the target version, not the host version of RHEL. So, you might be doing something strange. Are you not using `mock` to build your cross-version packages?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your first sentence. I am not using `mock`.

Comment: What I mean is that the problem you're experiencing, that `0%{?rhel}` evaluates to the version of Redhat of the machine you build on (RHEL7), is not a problem that I encounter; that is because when building packages for a different distro version, you don't use an `rpmbuild` environment targeting your build host (RHEL7 in your case), but one targeting your actual target (RHEL 8, 9 in your case). `mock` is just one way that makes that easy, but it is pretty much the standard way for redhatoids to achieve such cross-distro-version builds. It's pretty easy to use if you know how build an SRPM.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In my case, the target is all three versions (7, 8, and 9). I would prefer to only have one package that works on all three target distro versions, rather than one package for each distro version. I have been able to do so since I first released my s/w for RHEL over 6 years ago, but the problem with `redhat-lsb` is the first time we have encountered such a situation.

Comment: It looks like I might be able to solve the problem with the weak dependency `Recommends:`, but that is not available on RHEL7 :(

Comment: Well you can have one source package (srpm) and three rpms built from that. Dependencies in an rpm package are definite, not variable

Comment: And honestly, with mock it's literally no extra work building these three packages. Learn mock, be done.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll certainly look into mock. There is more to it for my company though.  We will have to update our software distribution infrastructure, documentation, licensing, etc.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Might simply be unavoidable. From a C++ developer/maintainer perspective I can tell you that not being able to use the same RPM for multiple distro versions is the norm, not the exception. You could minimize the impact by letting your "complex" package with licensed code and whatnot be the same for all versions of the distro ; let it depend on a "meta-package", which is actually different for different RHEL releases and does nothing but itself depend on the right things for each RHEL version.

Comment: Hu? Are you really using Requires? Because that is evaluated in run-time. It is the BuildRequires that is evaluated in build-time.